# How can I obtain the intensity values of an image, and what tools do you recommend for this task?

Tags: image-processing, computer-vision, image-segmentation

Hello friends,

I am currently working on image processing and I would like to obtain the intensity histogram of the attached image. As you may know, images are constructed using the intensity values of individual pixels, which typically range from 0 to 255. I am unsure of how to obtain this histogram and which tools would be best suited for the task. Could you please provide some guidance or suggestions?
Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: any image processing library out there can create histograms. even coding it yourself is super easy. all you have to do is to count how often each intensity value occurs in the image. for a quick solution you can use ImageJ, Gimp, ImageMagick,...

Answer (score 1):

The histogram you show doesn't match your scan - the scan has a very large number of dark pixels that aren't in the histogram.

Anyway, you can generate a histogram quite simply at the command-line with **ImageMagick** which is installed on most Linux distros and is available for macOS and Windows.

So, starting with this:

[image]

The command is like this:

```
convert image.jpg histogram:result.png
```

[image]

If you don't want it broken down by colour, you can convert to greyscale like this:

```
convert image.jpg -colorspace gray histogram:intensity.png
```

[image]

So, for your image:

```
convert scan.jpg histogram:scanI.png
```

[image]

If you want black on white, you can invert it and put a border around it:

```
convert scanI.png -negate -bordercolor black -border 1 scanI.png
```

[image]

If you want the values in a text format, you can use:

```
convert scan.jpg -colorspace gray -format %c histogram:info:-

     4: (  0,  0,  0) #000000 gray(0)
    10: (  1,  1,  1) #010101 gray(1)
     8: (  1,  1,  1) #010101 gray(1)
    19: (  2,  2,  2) #020202 gray(2)
     9: (  2,  2,  2) #020202 gray(2)
    52: (  3,  3,  3) #030303 gray(3)
    20: (  3,  3,  3) #030303 gray(3)
   116: (  4,  4,  4) #040404 gray(4)
    42: (  4,  4,  4) #040404 gray(4)
   321: (  5,  5,  5) #050505 gray(5)
   266: (  5,  5,  5) #050505 gray(5)
     5: (  5,  5,  5) #050505 gray(5)
 12058: (  6,  6,  6) #060606 gray(6)
    79: (  6,  6,  6) #060606 gray(6)
     1: (  6,  6,  6) #060606 gray(6)
   778: (  7,  7,  7) #070707 gray(7)
    66: (  7,  7,  7) #070707 gray(7)
     1: (  7,  7,  7) #070707 gray(7)
   269: (  8,  8,  8) #080808 gray(8)
    45: (  8,  8,  8) #080808 gray(8)
   127: (  9,  9,  9) #090909 gray(9)
    34: (  9,  9,  9) #090909 gray(9)
     1: (  9,  9,  9) #090909 gray(9)
    53: ( 10, 10, 10) #0A0A0A gray(10)
    27: ( 10, 10, 10) #0A0A0A gray(10)
    28: ( 11, 11, 11) #0B0B0B gray(11)
    23: ( 11, 11, 11) #0B0B0B gray(11)
    21: ( 12, 12, 12) #0C0C0C gray(12)
    28: ( 12, 12, 12) #0C0C0C gray(12)
    ...
    ...
```